# Apache/PHP cannot save to the public_html

Tags: apache-http-server, php, www

Apache and PHP are running as `nobody` user and group. `public_html` folder is set to:

```
drwxrwx---  11 myuser nobody  4096 Feb 11 14:39 public_html/
```

but when Apache and PHP (via Wordpress) tries to overwrite anything there it can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like upgrading Apache from 2.2 to 2.4 on WHM somehow removed suPHP. An answer from [that](https://superuser.com/a/457829/371804) question brought me on that direction.